# How to show alert only when error message isn´t empty in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, alert

I have a task to add alert component that you can close when CloseButton is clicked. I have done that and it works but task description continues: The usage of the finished component should go like this:
`<ErrorDialog error={error}>` where error is an error message. If that error is blanck, the dialog will not be displayed at all.

Here's my ErrorDialog.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, AlertDescription, CloseButton } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { Box } from '@chakra-ui/layout';

class ErrorDialog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isActive: true,
    };
  }

  hideError() {
    this.setState({ isActive: false, });
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isActive) {
      return (
        <Box className="ErrorDialog">
      <Alert status="error" position="fixed" top="0pt" left="0pt" bg="red.300" width="100%" height="40pt">
        <AlertDescription fontWeight="bold" color="white">{this.props.error}</AlertDescription>
        <CloseButton onClick={() => this.hideError()} position="absolute" right="8px" top="8px" color="black"/>
      </Alert>
      </Box>
      )
    }
    return !ErrorDialog
  }
}

export default ErrorDialog;
```

And here's the code of the page where ErrorDialog is showing up:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import LocalStorageService from '../../../Tools/LocalStorageService.js';
import Core from 'avainia-core-api';

//Partials
import FormHeader from '../../partials/FormHeader/FormHeader.js';
import InputTextboxWithAlert from '../../partials/InputTextboxWithAlert/InputTextboxWithAlert.js';
import InputTextbox from '../../partials/InputTextbox/InputTextbox.js';
import InputRadio from '../../partials/InputRadio/InputRadio.js';

import ErrorDialog from '../../partials/ErrorDialog/ErrorDialog.js';

//Icons
import { BsArrowRightShort } from "react-icons/bs";


//Chakras
import { Heading, Box, Text } from '@chakra-ui/layout';
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Icon from '@chakra-ui/icon';


class FormElements extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

}

render() {
  return (
    <Box className="FormElements">

    <ErrorDialog error="Message comes here"/>

      <Box p={[4, 8, 4, 8]}>
      <Box>
        <Heading className="heading" fontWeight="bold">Directions</Heading>
      </Box>
      </Box>

      <FormHeader text="Background"/>
      <InputTextboxWithAlert question="background here.
      What? When?"/>
      <FormHeader text="Contact details"/>
      <InputRadio radioQ="Is there the phone number"/>

          <Box p={4, 8, 4, 8}>
          <Text className="questions">Street address?</Text>
          <br></br>
          <Text fontSize="16">address here.</Text>
          <br></br>
          <InputTextbox/>

          <Box>
            <br></br>
            <Text className="questions">City?</Text>
            <br></br>
          <InputTextbox/>
          </Box>
          </Box>

          <Box className="forward-buttons">
            <ButtonGroup>
            <Button variant="green-forward-btn">Save</Button>
            <Button variant="yellow-forward-btn">Continue
            <Icon as={BsArrowRightShort} display={{ base: "none", xl: "block" }} w={6} h={6} color="black"/>
            </Button>
            </ButtonGroup>
          </Box>
          </Box>
      )
    }
  }


export default withRouter(FormElements);
```

How can I complete my task?

Comment: `if (this.state.isActive && this.props.error)`

Answer (score 0):

You can render the `ErrorDialog` UI only when the error is available and `isActive` is true.

```
render() {
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    const { error } = this.props;

    if (isActive && typeof error === 'string' && error.length > 0 ) {
      return (
        ...
      )
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Although there is a caveat with your method since this is an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), you won't display the error dialog again if you want once the user closes the dialog. You might want to make it a controlled component for more granular control from the parent component.